# How can I make images behave independently using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am new to programming, and studying remote. Right now we are doing jQuery and I am trying to get my images change opacity independently. I have manged to get them to change opacity on MouseOver, but they all change at the same time. How can I differnciate images in jQuery?
 I use MouseOut, animate and Opacity.

Remember I am new to this and my references limited;)

Marthe

Comment: Whatever you're doing to modify the images now, you would target a specific image instead of all of them.  Of course, we don't know what you're *currently* doing...

Comment: Please provide what have you done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing where 'image' is the class you have assigned to the images,

```
$('.image').mouseOver(function(){
$('.image').hide();
});
```

try using this

```
$('.image').mouseOver(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
```